# "Error encountered while BER decoding" in Adobe Acrobat Pro X when applying timestamp

Tags: adobe-acrobat, timestamp, digital-signature

I have a tedious problem with Acrobat Pro X 10.1.3.23: when I want to apply a timestamp to a document I always get that error.

I have configured VeriSign TSA server `http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll` and it returns that error. I have tried Comodo CA `http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode` and Aruba `https://servizi.arubapec.it/tsa/ngrequest.php` but all three returned the same exact error. My PDFs are now signed without a certified timestamp and this is a problem for me.

I'm obliged to sign documents and apply a certified timestamp at the same time.

This seems to be a common error in Acrobat, but I found no solution to it.

Can somebody help me?

[Update] Thanks to Wireshark I found this

Request

```
POST /scripts/timstamp.dll HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/timestamp-query
Content-Length: 53
Character-Encoding: binary
User-Agent: PPKHandler
Host: timestamp.verisign.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

03...0!0...+.............031.z&...y.z......+[.JeG....
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Netscape-Enterprise/4.1
Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 16:01:42 GMT
Content-type: application/timestamp-query
Content-length: 39

error handling request, status = 0x9300
```

I don't know if the request is well-formed

[image: Screenshot of ASN.1 decode]

Answer (score -1):

The time stamp server is not free of charge. So, this servers reject your request. you can use free time stamp servers.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a `free time stamp server` that djechelon is able to solve his problem?

Comment: AFAIK Verisign's TSA is free of charge. And Aruba is not free of charge but I have paid for that!